# How to replace a manual id with an ObjectID _id in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a database with two collections, kids and classes. Each kid belongs to one class.

Each class has a previously created integer id.

I want to replace the kid.class_id with the (ObjectID) _id of the class, not the (integer) id of the class.

However, when I run the script below, it doesn't reset the class_id with the class._id -- it remains the old integer id.

```
  mongoose.connect(someMongodbUri, { useMongoClient: true }, (err, db) => {

    let kidsCount = 0;

    db.collection('kids').find({}).each((err, kid) => {

      kidsCount++;

      db.collection('classes')
        .findOne({ id: kid.class_id })
        .then((class, err) => {

          let newClassId = class._id;

          db.collection('kids').updateOne(
            { _id: kid._id },
            { $set: { class_id: newClassId } }
          ).then(() => {
              console.info('Updated', kid.class_id);
              kidsCount--;
              if (kidsCount === 0) { db.close(); }
            });
        });
    });
  });
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert integerId to Object id.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
let newClassId = ObjectId(class._id);
```

There may be better or elegent ways that i don't know, but this works for me.